# How to synthesise music vocals?

Tags: music, text-to-speech

Early text-to-speech tools that I tested had limited singing capabilities. I've heard that they evolved and now are available as commercial products. I would like to know what sw can do this and where I can buy such products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard of [Vocaloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocaloid) which seems to be the sort of thing you're looking for but I don't know the field.

Comment: I finally found some Vocaloid products at http://www.zerogdownload.com/store/category/42/Vocaloid for $79.99 each

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking of using regular text to speech tools with Autotune or [Celemony's Direct Note Access](http://www.celemony.com/cms/index.php?id=dna)

Comment: that link is now broken